# Redundancy for tour button on sites I haven't joined

Tags: discussion, design, top-bar

Curious as to why  there is a redundancy on the **tour** button on SE sites that I haven't "Joined the community" to.

Not only is it under the 'help' menu but also on the main menu next to 'join this community'.  I believe we should eliminate the one on the main menu.  Anyone looking for help will see the tour immediately.  Think **LESS IS MORE**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fine to have it twice. For something as important as the Tour, you want there to be multiple paths for people to find it.